# Importing p5 in typescript class

Tags: typescript, p5.js

I'm learning some p5 stuff from Coding train, but I'm writing everything in Typescript/webpack project.

I am using p5 as an instance, and my code works fine, but I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong.

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';

export class Particlehelper {
  private pos: p5.Vector;
  private vel: p5.Vector;
  private accl: p5.Vector;

  public constructor(p: p5) {
    this.pos = p.createVector(p.random(p.windowWidth), p.random(p.windowHeight));
    // this.vel = p.createVector(0, 0);
    this.vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
    this.accl = p.createVector(0, 0);
  }
```

What confuses me here is - I'm importing P5 as I need class properties to be of type Vector, but then in order to instanciate vector, I'm passing P5 to the constructor from index file.

```
particles[i] = new Particlehelper(p);
```

I have a feeling that is wrong - it sounds to me like I'm doing the same thing twice, but I could not untangle how to use just imported p5 within the class.

As well - I've never seen "public constructor" notation, but linter forced me to add it there - not sure if that is OK or not?

Thanks,

Comment: pls share how you call this `particles[i] = new Particlehelper(p);`

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. What do you mean with passing it from index file? Your constructor looks fine, it says that it expects a parameter `p` of the type `p5`. You're not getting any TypeScript errors?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs - no, as I said - code works fine, no errors. What I don't understand is the need to pass p:p5 to constructor, instead of using p5 that is imported in line 1. I see it as "double work", but I might be wrong, and that's where I'm looking for clarification.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - that's how I'm calling it. It's within for loop as it creates 100 particles, but that's it, nothing to share there. Question is - could I just do "new Particlehelper()" without passing p, and "reuse" or "instanciate" p within the class since I am importing it there on line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fine. The thing about `p5.Vector` is that it is a bit odd because it 1) doesn't declare it's actual constructor arguments, 2) may be constructed with a reference to a p5 instance. The reason for this is that there are functions on `p5.Vector` that take a sketches `angleMode` into account (`DEGREES` or `RADIANS`). When you create a `p5.Vector` with `createVector` the resulting vector has a reference to the `p5` instance and will respect its angle mode. But you can also create a vector statically, and vectors created that way will not respect the sketches angle mode:

```
    p.angleMode(p.DEGREES);

    let v1 = p.createVector(1, 0);
    let v2 = p.createVector(0, 1);
    // Result is in degrees
    console.log(v1.angleBetween(v2));

    v1 = new p5.Vector();
    v1.set(1, 0);
    v2 = new p5.Vector();
    v2.set(0, 1);
    // Result is in radians
    console.log(v1.angleBetween(v2));
```

Note that `p5.Vector.random2d` is also going to create a vector that uses the default angle mode (radians).